# How can I find location of resource file loaded in TWebBrowser when running GMLib?

Tags: gmlib

I am running GMLib in XE7 and we are using a Google API Client ID (as opposed to an API Key).  I have successfully modified the map.html to include the Client ID.  I recompiled the resource files and GMLib and that is all working.  However, because of the use of the Client ID, I need to give Google all possible locations that will be using our Client ID.  If it were a web app, it would be the URL, but in this case I can give them the file location.

I assume the GMMap control generates a local html file based on the resource file and this file is loaded in the TWebBrowser.  How can I find the file location because that is what Google is verifying against our Client ID?  I tried looking for it a different events, but it always seems to show `about:blank`.

Answer (score 0):

GMLib don't create a local file with HTML page. You need to change TCustomGMMap.GetAPIUrl method. This methid returns a string with the HTML code